# Error with | in Swift

Tags: swift

Can someone explain me why it shows error here. I follow the tutorial, but maybe in swift 2, it doesn't true if typing like this.

[image]

Comment: For one thing, you are misssing `.Alert` in the beginning. Also Swift 2 came with a new syntax for options, now `[.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]`. is used.

Comment: @Sulthan - Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Wezly I was looking for the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you @Sulthan , It worked. I have just learned swift 2.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably following tutorial from older version of Swift. Since its growing really fast, I suggest following the newest tutorials. In Swift 2 you should use collection, not | binary operator. Like:

```
[UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Badge]
```

Comment: This should be [.Sound, .Badge, .Alert]

Comment: Despite missing `.Alert` - there is still nothing wrong with using the full reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the first `UIUserNotificationType`, which is missing (I guess) the `.Alert` part.